# Test coverage is 70%

Tags: unit-test

Please help on the test coverage for my trigger

Trigger:

```
Trigger DemoReportCount on Demo_Report__c (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

   List<Demo_Request__c> ct = new List<Demo_Request__c>();
   List<Id> custord = new List<Id>();

   if(Trigger.isDelete) {
     **for(Demo_Report__c test:Trigger.Old) {

        custord.add(test.Demo_Request__c);**     

     }   

   }
   else
   if(Trigger.isUpdate) {

     **for(Demo_Report__c test:Trigger.New) {

        custord.add(test.Demo_Request__c);   

     }

     for(Demo_Report__c test:Trigger.Old) {

        custord.add(test.Demo_Request__c);**   

     }   

   }
   else
   {
     for(Demo_Report__c test:Trigger.New) {

        custord.add(test.Demo_Request__c);   

     }
   }

   AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(Id), Demo_Request__c FROM Demo_Report__c where Demo_Request__c IN :custord GROUP BY Demo_Request__c ];

   for(AggregateResult ar:groupedResults) {

     Id custid = (ID)ar.get('Demo_Request__c');

     Integer count = (INTEGER)ar.get('expr0');

     Demo_Request__c cust1 = new Demo_Request__c(Id=custid);

     cust1.Demo_Reports__c = count;

     ct.add(cust1);

   }

   update ct;
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
private class DemoReportCount_Test {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        // TO DO: implement unit test
        Set<Id> optyIds = new Set<Id>();


     List<Demo_Request__c> ct = new List<Demo_Request__c>();

   List<Id> custord = new List<Id>();


      Demo_Request__c dreq = new Demo_Request__c(Name = 'test', Territory__c = 'NASA');
      insert dreq;

      Demo_Report__c drep  = new Demo_Report__c(Name = 'testing', Demo_Request__c = dreq.Id);
      insert drep;

    }
}
```

Comment: how do we what is not covered?

Comment: After nearly 3 years here, I would have thought you would know how to format code in a question... I would suggest taking a look at [how to format](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it wasn't formatted, and is missing some important information like: 1) which lines are/are not covered? 2) There are many similar questions here, what research have you done? 3) What have you tried to do to increase your coverage, where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Highlighted the lines in bold that are not covered, but below are the lines        
    for(Demo_Report__c test:Trigger.New) {   
        custord.add(test.Demo_Request__c);   
    
     }

     for(Demo_Report__c test:Trigger.Old) {
 
        custord.add(test.Demo_Request__c);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using a tool like **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)** in order to implement rollups without needing to write your own tests for them. It also works on undelete, an event for which you have neglected the applicable logic.

---

You haven't updated or deleted any records in your test. When you have event specific logic, you have to fire that event in order to run that logic. From a strictly minimalistic perspective, all you really need to do is call all three DML Operations you filter on:

```
insert record;
update record;
delete record;
```

However, coverage does *not* a unit test make. Note from **[How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)** (emphasis mine):

> #### [Verify the results are correct](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests#Verify_the_results_are_correct)
>
> *Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is the most important part of unit testing*. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as [smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests.
>
> A good way to tell if unit tests are properly verifying results is to look for liberal use of the `System.assert()` methods. If there aren’t any `System.assert()` method calls, then the tests aren’t verifying results properly. And, no, `System.assert(true);` doesn’t count.

In light of the above, you are missing the very most important aspect of unit testing. You haven't verified any application behavior, but rather just "smoke tested" it by running the logic and seeing if any of it throws an exception (starts to smoke).

Comment: Only reason i didn't use roll up was this is lookup relationship and i want to have sharing rules, if i change it to master detail i can't create sharing rules on child

Comment: That is the entire reason the Declarative *Lookup* Rollup Summaries tool exists.

Comment: So you are saying we can create roll up fields in lookup relationship? is it standard salesforce behavior or custom app? could you please send me the link for that?

Comment: @Admin_BA It's a custom app. I linked to it at the top of my post.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will install the app , i really hate triggers

Comment: Yeah, clicks not code in this case is a big win. @Admin_BA